# What do you do for "a" living?

Tags: definite-article

I read this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152460/why-do-we-say-what-do-you-do-for-a-living) so I understood why we need an article in the sentence

> What do you do for a living?

My question is why we use `a living` not `the living`, since we are asking certain somebody, shouldn't we use `the` instead of `a`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible 'livings' - i.e., professions, vocations, jobs.  So I have 'a living', not 'the living'.

[living](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/living) (MW, noun definition 2)

> means of subsistence : livelihood

Comment: Still confused, I know what exactly I do for a living, shouldn't I say `I have the living`?

Comment: @Ives, this might just be a case where the normal grammatical rules don't match how the word has come to be used.  "The living" is a phrase used to describe the collection of people who are alive.  People might say, "I make **my** living doing XYZ." to refer to their own specific source of livelihood.  Otherwise, it is treated as an example of livelihoods, and "a" is used.

Comment: @Ives I know exactly what kind of car I own, but I don't say "I have the car"...

Comment: @JohnFeltz yes, this is why I'm confused. I thought I should use `the` when something is specific.

Comment: "I have a car." (out of many cars in the world)  "The car I own is green."  "The green car over there is mine."